# install xmonad with no priveledges

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, xmonad

I would like to install and use xmonad on a RHEL box to which I only have access my home directory and the usual unprivileged access. How can I install it?

P.S. No Haskell compiler or xlibs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no sudo access and no Haskell compiler, then the answer is no.  There are prebuilt binaries for Fedora 10 and onward, looks as if it's an [official part of the Fedora repository](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/packages/name/xmonad?_csrf_token=94c51e24b1eb3e677cf31f3dd1da96f68571290b) now, meaning that eventually it may be in some future RHEL version too. Don't hold your breath though.

Answer (score 3):

If you build with the Haskell 'cabal-install' tool, it will happily install as user, and modify no global files.

```
cabal install xmonad --prefix=$HOME
```

Comment: I'm assuming that not already having a haskell compiler will prevent cabal?

Comment: @Arthur: If you do not already have a Haskell compiler then just download one and compile it...or grab the package and use --prefix to put it somewhere in your home directories.